# How to get formatted DateTime irrespective of the time zone in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

We use `formatGMT()` or `format()` methods of date time object in apex, it returns the formatted date based on the time zone. Although what should be done if we have a static date, such as date of birth that needs to be formatted, irrespective of the local time zone.
In my scenario when using `DateTime.format()`, The date of birth is showing correctly for users in India, although for the users in US, yesterday's date is displayed in some cases. In some cases it's converted correctly.

For eg. The dob for x person is 1995-09-20 which gets formatted to 09/20/1995,
Whereas for y person, the same method generates a formatted date 05/15/1990 when dob is 1990-05-16.
Basically the formatted date should be the exact replica of the dob, irrespective of time zone.

Method:

```
private static String localeFormatDate (Date dateValue) {
    try{
        String format = String.isNotBlank (strDateFormat) ? strDateFormat: 'MM/dd/YYYY';
        Date myDate = Date.newInstance (dateValue.year(), dateValue.month(), dateValue.day()); 
        Time myTime = Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0); 
        return DateTime.newInstanceGMT (myDate, myTime). format GMT (format);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        return null;
    }
```

}

Additionally, I have also tried to set timezone as Asia/Colombo as the date is correctly formatted in that time zone:

```
return DateTime.newInstanceGMT(myDate, myTime).format (format, 'Asia/Colombo');
```

Although I'm not sure if that would generate the correct format date based on the when the method runs.